# Creating a dictionary from 2 lists with same keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

as i m beginner in python.
I have below 2 lists:

```
list1 =['abc','cbd','efg']
list2['applicationName','appllicationName','appllicationName']
```

output i am expected like below:

```
[{'appllicationName':'abc'},{'appllicationName':'cbd'},{'appllicationName':'efg'}]
```

using dict,zip function i am getting only below output:

```
{'appllicationName':'efg'}
```

please help me resolve this.

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters and also code formating. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also keep in mind we don't do your homework here. Show us what you have tried so far please. If you have to try first before asking.

Comment: If you show the actual code you tried, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid Python expression. It is not possible to have a `dict` with duplicated keys.

Comment: it is a valid python expression, except that python picks the last key and drops the rest.

Comment: @buhtz modified the expected output :                                   
    [{'appllicationName':'abc'},{'appllicationName':'cbd'},{'appllicationName':'efg'}]

Comment: you probably need a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to have a key => list of strings dictionary

Comment: But you still didn't modify your misspelling. Please use correct upper case letters. Sentences always starting with an upper case letter. Also the `i` in English is written upper case. Please read carefully the links I showed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want. But I assume you need a list of 3 single dictionaries. But @Manuel 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76323652/4865723) with one dictionary seems better to me.

Anyway... Sticking to your example code you can do it like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
list1 = ['abc', 'cbd', 'efg']
list2 = ['applicationName', 'appllicationName', 'appllicationName']

# Method 1
result_one = [{key: val} for key, val in zip(list2, list1)]

# Method 2 assumes that the key name is always the same.
key = 'applicationName'
result_two = [{key: val} for val in list1]
```

Both methods give you

```
[{'applicationName': 'abc'}, {'applicationName': 'cbd'}, {'applicationName': 'efg'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant have the same key twice in a Python Dictionary, so he only takes the last key:value since you always replace them. You could add the Values to the same Key like this:

```
list1 =['abc','cbd','efg']
list2 = ['appllicationName','appllicationName','appllicationName']
my_dict = {}
for key, value in zip(list2, list1):
   if key not in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] = []
   my_dict[key].append(value)

print(my_dict)
```

Here the output will be:

```
{'appllicationName': ['abc', 'cbd', 'efg']}
```